# window.location.hash refresh in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, location

I was doing some snooping on the web and found `window.location.hash = "etc"` to be a widely adopted method to update the browser's location without reloading / refreshing the page. I've applied that to this example I've cooked up: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1595444/locationExample/index.html

Works well in Safari, but...

What I've noticed is that in Chrome 10+ upon changing `hash`:

There is something similar to a reload.

The resulting symptom is a hiccup as the user scrolls down or up.

My console output is preserved (if you check your console the project string's are outputted).

The favicon seems to be reloading.

Has anyone run into this problem before? Know a fix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are most likely two things going on here:

- The favicon and stop/refresh buttons flicker because of [a Chrome bug](http://crbug.com/50298) (that mentions `pushState`, but hash changes are
  on the same code path).
- The slight hiccup when scrolling is because Chrome does a full page repaint and high-quality scale to update the page thumbnail, since it's considering hash changes as generating a new URL. That's also [a bug](http://crbug.com/62820). You can see this in the inspector timeline view, most scroll events result in a repaint of *window width* x *some small height*, but occasionally there will be a full-window repaint. [This blog post](http://blog.persistent.info/2010/11/chrome-performance-puzzler.html) has a few more details.

A workaround for both would be to defer the updating of the hash until the user is done scrolling (you can still update the white bar that appears under the current item immediately). You can do this by having something like:

```
var scrollTimeout;
window.onscroll = function() {
  // update current item display here
  if (scrollTimeout)
    clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
  scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    scrolTimeout = undefined;
     // update hash here
  }, 100);
};
```

Since it looks like you're using jQuery, there are [debouncing plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/debounce) that may be helpful.

Comment: Currently jumping to anchors is only working if there is no hash set. (eg: your.tld/blog#comment-1) To jump to a new anchor you have to set the hash to null (window.location.hash = null) before applying the new hash (window.location.hash = '#comment-2')and than it works. Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a definitive answer, but first I would try:

1. Prepending the hash mark (#) on to the value (i.e. use window.location.hash = "#etc").
2. Register a handler for the [window.onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) handler.
3. Alternatively, you might consider using [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history) if what you are trying to accomplish is make the back button return to the previous logical  location (it's not clear to me what you are trying accomplish, whether you just want to jump to  a section on the page, or something more complex).

Comment: http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-discuss/browse_thread/thread/5e8cc6b1ee6c470f

Answer (score 1):

```
var r='#hello';
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome/')!=-1){
 top.history.pushState("", "", r);
 return;
};
if(r.charAt(0)=='/'){
  top.location.replace(r);
 }else{
  top.location.hash=r;
};
```

Worked for me. And it actually took me a long time to figure this out. Firefox also supports the `history` object now, so we may be able to get rid of the whole "hash" thing in a few years.

EDIT: Yes, the reloading thing is a Chrome bug.