# change Window.location with javascript even while using hash?

Tags: javascript

I want to refresh with new hash but it seems chrome just changes the hash instead of redirecting as it's the same URL.

How can I do it?

```
window.location = "http://lujanventas.com/" + shopURL + "#" + name;
```

Comment: you shouldn't be using `window.location` but `window.location.href`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Comment: I think you are looking for this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5657192/498609

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to slightly change the URL with a URL parameter to force the browser to reget the page:

```
window.location = "http://lujanventas.com/" + shopURL + "?random=" + (new Date()) + "#" + name;
```

By definition a hash change only is only supposed to just go to that hash - it isn't supposed to reload the page so the way you have it now, it's doing what it's generally supposed to.  Without explicitly doing a page reload first, you have to trick it into loading the URL over again when you change the hash.  Adding a different parameter to the URL will trick it.

Comment: I like the idea. Untill a solution appears that simply refreshes I take this one. Thanks