# Why browser update header when i set url using hash?

Tags: javascript, hash, window.location

I use `window.location.hash = mylink` to set url every time user move map (add coordinates). But it's always look like page loading (favicon reloads). How to do that page update url without reloading?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3354511/1360261) may be of use.

Comment: If you only see this behavior on Chrome, it is most likely a Chrome bug as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657083/window-location-hash-refresh-in-chrome

Answer (score 0):

I just checked on Chrome and although it does indeed look like the favicon refreshes, there is no network traffic.